# How to use boost hash_value in std unordered_set?

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-set

How can I use `boost::hash_value<std::pair<>>` in `std::unordered_set<std::pair<>>` without defining a functor?

The following doesn't work:

```
        typedef std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> S;

        typedef size_t (hash_value_sample)(const S&);
        std::function<hash_value_sample> hasher = 
                    static_cast<hash_value_sample&>(boost::hash_value<unsigned, unsigned>);

        std::unordered_set<S, decltype(hasher)> set;
        set.insert(S(10, 10));
```

The execution aborts.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call'
  what():  bad_function_call
Abort
```

I think the above doesn't work because hasher() doesn't exist. I am using g++ -std=c++14

Comment: Here is mcve: https://godbolt.org/z/nYsr5M4e1

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work, according to my tests:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

typedef std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> S;
typedef boost::hash<S> hash_t;

int main() {
  std::unordered_set<S, hash_t> set;
  set.insert(S(10, 10));
  std::cout << set.count(S(10, 10)) << std::endl;
  std::cout << set.count(S(10, 9)) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
❯ clang++ test.cpp -o test && ./test
1
0
```

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. If I have an existing hash function, then how do I use it in STL associative containers without enclosing it in a new functor?

Comment: @user3689963 You don't. Neither does this answer: `using` doesn't introduce new types and the standard `hash<>` specialization gets inlined (same as for `std::hash<>`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a lambda:

```
auto hasher = [] (S s) { return boost::hash_value (s); };
std::unordered_set<S, decltype(hasher)> set;
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Uw3Uz5FyScA99Jhi)

Comment: Works only since c++20 where lambda are defult constructible.

Comment: @rafix07 Oh yes...  Well, maybe the OP can use it.

Comment: @rafix07 you ahve been faster: https://wandbox.org/permlink/3fmBWivrTSBGsOAE